# friend function and copy constructors

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor, friend-function

The code shown below doesn't compile when the friend function mag() is defined inside the class, but works if defined outside class (commented). I think the difference is caused by the copy constructor used to change the argument type from A to B. Can someone explain why I should define the friend function outside?

Moreover, if class B is a template class (adding `template <class T>` at the top), defining the friend function outside will also not work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
};

class B {
public:
    B(const  A& p) {
        std::cout << "Copy/Conversion constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    friend void mag(const B& p) {
        std::cout << "Mag Inside`.\n";
    }
};
//void mag(const B& p) {
//     std::cout << "Mag Outside.\n";
//}
int main() {
    A a;
    mag(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `B(const A&)` is a conversion constructor not a copy constructor. You also didn't specify what error you get when compiling.

Comment: The error is 'error: use of undeclared identifier 'mag''.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the function `mag` is not *declared* in the global scope (you did defined and declared it when you made it a friend at the same time, but the declaration in it's own scope is still required).

You need to declare it :

```
class B {
public:
    B(const  A& p) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    friend void mag(const B& p) {
        std::cout << "Mag Inside`.\n";
    }
};

void mag(const B& p);
```

If you call `mag` with a `B` object, [Argument Dependant Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) will look into `B`'s scope and find the definition.

Now if `B` is a template, you'll need to declare each version of `mag` with the appropriate parameters (and if several exist, you'll need to help the compiler to resolve ambiguities during conversions) :

```
template<typename T>
class B {
public:
    B(const  A& p) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    friend void mag(const B<T>& p) {
        std::cout << "Mag Inside`.\n";
    }
};

void mag(const B<int>& p);  // Version for B<int> declared.
```

Comment: Ok that works, but isn't it enough to just define a member function as a 'friend' to give it a global scope? If the copy-constructor was not involved, f.i passing a B object to mag directly, doesn't need mag to be declared outside ...

Comment: No it is no enough. The second case works only because of [argument dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), the global scope declaration is still missing for any other case.

Comment: Ok thanks. If class B is a template class, defining the function outside doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think one version would be enough. I was able to call a B<double> object while still having the mag for B<int> declared.

Answer (score 2):

Sections of the C++ Draft Standard N3337 that are relevant for this question:

> **11.3 Friends**
>
> 4 A function first declared in a friend declaration has external linkage (3.5). Otherwise, the function retains its previous linkage (7.1.1).
>
> 6 A function can be defined in a friend declaration of a class if and only if the class is a non-local class (9.8), the function name is unqualified, and the function has namespace scope. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> class M {
>     friend void f() { } // definition of global f, a friend of M,
>                         // not the definition of a member function
>  };
> ```
>
> *— end example* ]
>
> 7 Such a function is implicitly `inline`. A friend function defined in a class is in the (lexical) scope of the class in which it is defined. A friend function defined outside the class is not (3.4.1).

In your example, `mag` is defined in the lexical scope of class `B`, i.e. the name `mag` is not visible outside the class even though it has external linkage. To make the function visible outside the class `B`, it has to be declared outside `B`.

Answer (score 0):

`mag` is not declared in global scope. Also, [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) kicks in during the function overload resolution case, but it is strictly based on the types of the argument - not on [implicity-convertible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) types. If you want to use ADL, call `mag` with a `B`.

```
int main() {
    A a;
    mag(B(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you move the definition of `mag` inside `A` (and forward declare `B` above `struct A`) then [the code also compiles.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/629890ef0c3645b3)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Agreed. Although if the intention is to use ADL, and not pollute the global namespace, `mag` belongs inside `B`'s definition.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not on implicitly-convertible types". Did ADL not kick in [in my example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/629890ef0c3645b3) and implicitly convert `A` to `B const&`?

Comment: In your example, ADL introduced `mag` defined in `A`'s scope into the set of overloads to consider during function overload resolution. In OP's example, ADL would not introduce it to the set of overloads considered, because the function's argument type is `A`. My point was just that even though `A` can be implicity converted to `B`, something from `B`'s scope would not be introduced by ADL into the set of valid overloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define friend function like that for a class if that class was a template, because :

suppose you have for example `B<int>` and `B<float>` it will be ambiguous for  the compiler whether to treat B as `B<int>` or `B<float>`

therefore you must declare mag as a template as well like that :

```
// Inside the class :
friend void mag(const B<T>& p);

// Outside the class :
template <typename T> void mag(const B<T>& p) {
     std::cout << "Mag Outside.\n";
}
```

then it will work!

Comment: It does not work unless I do mag<int>(a). It would be convenient if I can still call it as mag(a)

Comment: if u want to define ur own int function of mag just edit mag to be like this :
void mag(const B<int>& p) {
     std::cout << "Mag Outside.\n";
}
if u want to declare mag for all types int, float,.. just define it inside the class body, like a normal function because no need to the keyword friend

Answer (score 0):

1.
if class B is not a template class, you must define mag function outside class because it is a friend function which means that it is a non-class-member-function.

```
class B{
    public:
        B(const A& p){
            cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;
        }    
        friend void mag(const B& p);
    private:
        int k;
};

void mag(const B& p){
    cout<<"mag"<<endl;
}
```

2.
if class B is a template class, you should add template<...> statement both in function declaration and definition.

```
template<class T>
class B{
    public:
        B(const T& p){
            cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;
        }
        template<class T2>        //declare mag as a template function
        friend void mag(const T2& p);
};

template<class T>    //define mag function
void mag(const T& p){
    cout<<"mag\n";
}
```

Comment: "must define function mag outside class" is incorrect. but if you change it to "must declare function mag outside class" then it holds for this particular case. maybe add some qualification to make that clear.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-alf-----please read the comment on my excerpt code above. That's what I mean as a function definition, i.e, function definition is a function declaration complete with it's body.